# Create a for loop in MASM with a variable to create distinct PROC functions

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, masm

I'm trying to create a set of procs based on a 'for loop' counter. MASM doesn't appear to have a traditional for-next type loop, so I'm trying to use a variable and REPT.

Eg:

```
ix = 0
rept 2
    foo_&ix& proc
        mov rax, ix
        ret
    foo_&ix& endp
    ix = ix + 1
endm

...

; call the generated procs
call foo_0
call foo_1
```

However ml64.exe is returning `error A2008: syntax error : foo_`, so it's like it isn't using the variable.

I assume I'm not defining and using variables correctly. Constants are created with `ix equ 0`, but these don't appear to be able to be altered.

Comment: I think you are going to have to use something like `TEXTEQU` to equate a string to the constant value `ix` and then use a % (expression operator) to generate the lines that need the text replacement. You could also use CATSTR. It has been a while but I think you can do something like: https://pastebin.com/86rwSgWt . Some extra info that may be useful is here: http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=5703.0 . In my example I use `$` on the end of `ix$` to denote a `string`, which is just a convention I use so I know it is a string value.

Comment: Thanks, sadly no dice with the example. I've been searching masm32.org all day!

Comment: With that example what errors do you get? Not the same A2008 errors? It should in fact work unless you have something else in your code that is interfering.

Comment: The same errors; `syntax error at foo_`. there is something very odd with how MASM64 uses variables.

Comment: The variable are actually numbers, but numbers can't be directly appended to strings. So you have to convert the number to a string and then use text substitution to do the replacements. I'd like to see a copy of your code where you do what I suggested so I can see the errors for myself. There are a lot of old tutorials that get this wrong. I hope you didn't remove the `%` from the beginning of the lines in the example.

Comment: The version that uses `@CATSTR` which should also work would look like: https://pastebin.com/E8mjx0cJ . `@CATSTR` will concatenate multiple string expressions into an output string. It too builds the `foo_#` function names for the `PROC` statements

Comment: Ah! That does indeed do it. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPetch do you want to fill out an answer, so I can mark it as done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments above, use CatStr:

```
.code
ix = 0
rept 2
    @CatStr(<foo_>, %ix, < proc>)
    mov rax, ix
    ret
    @CatStr(<foo_>, %ix, < endp>)
    ix = ix + 1
endm

...
 
; call the generated procs
    call foo_0
    call foo_1
```

All credit to @Micheal Petch